# Having trouble implementing libGDX pause

Tags: libgdx, box2d, pausing

I tried to make pause button. 
When users click Pause button on a screen, a window came out then, game is frozen until users press continue button in the window .  my code is able to pop up window, but not freezing a game...

Let me please know..

```
 public class Pause(){
   .....
   public Pause(){

.....
TextButton pauseButton = new TextButton("Pause",  new 
Skin(Gdx.files.internal("x/myui.json")));
    pauseButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

           //>>here, I think I have to make it pause  

            final Window pause = new Window("PAUSE", skin); // pop up window

            TextButton continueButton = new TextButton("continue", skin);
            continueButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                    pause.setVisible(false);
                }
            });

            pause.add(continueButton).row();
            pause.add(new TextButton("exit", skin));
            pause.pack();
            //pause.setSize(stage.getWidth() / 1.5f, stage.getHeight() / 1.5f);
            //pause.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2 - pause.getWidth() / 2, stage.getHeight() / 2 - pause.getHeight() / 2);


            stage.addActor(pause);

        }
    });
    table.add(continueButton).top();
    stage.addActor(continueButton);

}
```

}
}

Comment: Great question, not well worded but thats ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another more convenient way to pause your game: delta time manipulation. I prefer delta time manipulation because you do not have to individually place `if(!isPaused) ...` everywhere in your code - only at the very start of your game loop. Pausing your game using delta time manipulation is simply achieved by setting `deltaTime = 0` at the start of your loop.

```
void render(float delta) {
    if (isPaused) 
        delta = 0;

    doLogic(delta);
    physicsWorld.step(delta, 6, 2);
    doRendering();

    // We don't want our UI to be paused so we use unscaled delta time 
    // for UI calculations. Unscaled delta time can be accessed using
    // Gdx.graphics.deltaTime().
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.deltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually, not LibGDX related at all. You just need to set a flag on your code `boolean isPaused = false;`  or something alike, and change its value upon pausing:

```
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
    isPaused = !isPaused;
    //...
}
```

Change your main loop accordingly, and only call your logic and Box2D's `world.update()` if `isPaused` is false, that is:

```
void render() {
    //Calc dt, etc
    if(!isPaused) {
        doLogic(); //Your game logic
        physicsWorld.step(dt, 5, 5); //Box2D's World
    }
    stage.act(); //LibGDX Scene2D's UI Stage logic
    doRendering(); //Your game rendering
    stage.draw();
}
```

This should do.